# Excel weight calculations

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm really new to excel and was wondering how I could take the info below and if one of the items was not a full box, and contains say 5 eaches of that product instead of 40, how I could enter that number of eaches and it calculate the new weight of the case of items.

Say a full case contains 40 eaches and weighs 30lb but the order is for 5 eaches I would like to be able to enter that number of eaches in a different cell and it calculate the new weight in another cell.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Figure out how you would do it with pen and paper then do it in excel (5/40*30) but use cell references.

Comment: You will probably need the tare weight of the container if you are going to use the case weight to determine the eaches weight. Frankly, though, the math for this is trivial: full-case-eaches-count divided by (full-case-weight minus full-case-tare-weight-#1) times partial-case-eaches-count plus partial-case-tare-weight-#2

Answer (score 1):

In one Cell A1 for example write **=30/40**
In B1 write the number of eaches you need **5**
In C1 write **=A1*B1**
C1 will give you automatically the new weight for 5 eaches or whatever number you write in B1